# Yii2 Почему не работает findOne(['like','fio','Pup']);?

Tags: php, yii2

Добра всем.
Имею таблицу в которой есть колонка fio и строка Vasya Pupkin
Объясните почему код

```
$model = Orders::find() 
     ->where(['like','fio','Pup'])
     ->one();
```

Выдает мне этого Васю, а

```
$model = Orders::findOne(['like','fio','Pup']);
```

Ничего не выдает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что findOne так не работает, вот что говорит [документация](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findOne()-detail):

> Returns a single active record model instance by a primary key or an
>   array of column values.

Если в этот метод передают массив, то как ключ передают поле и значение - значение в этом поле, ищет точное совпадение. Так что в Вашем случае только 1 вариант.

Answer (score 1):

В случае передачи в метод findOne() условия в виде неасоциированного массива это условие будет применено к первичному ключу вашей таблицы.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#findOne()-detail

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/BaseActiveRecord.php#L105